# how to change years to months using carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I just started using `Carbon`, I was able to make the program work in computing the years from the given date. But now I want to make the format counting the months, this is my code:

```
public function getAgeAttribute() {   
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['emp_birth_date'])->age;
}
```

I tried using the code:

```
->format('months');
```

but got an error I don't know where make it work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in method for getting age in Months, but it should be pretty simple to solve:

```
$ageInYears = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($birthday)->age;
$ageInMonths = $ageInYears * 12;
```

This isn't perfect, as age is not returned as a decimal, so 10 years could be anywhere between 120 and 131 months.

If you want something more accurate, you can use `diffInMonths` like so:

```
$ageInMonths = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInMonths(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($birthday));
```

Also, `->format("months");` is invalid, as `"months"` is not a valid PHP date format. Also also, `->format("m")` (which is the correct value) wouldn't work on `->age`, as `->age` returns an `int`, not a `Carbon` date.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for all the available PHP date formatting options.

Comment: Sorry for not expressing my question very well, English is my Second language. But thanks for your answer it gave me an idea on how to solve my problem. :)

Comment: No problem; I had no trouble understanding the question. Glad you got it working :)